# How to design interfaces to result in easy testing in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an requirement in which, I will be having two classes for handling two repository, say `Git` and `Svn`. The operations on these two repository is going to be same:

1. Get branches
2. Get commit ids
3. Get last commit file
4. etc

I thought I can design an interface which cover these operations:

```
interface Repo{
   public JSONObject getBranches()
   public JSONObject getCommits()
   . . . . 
}
```

Now the class `Git` and `Svn` can implement `Repo`. All is good.

But the question comes, how we are going to test these interfaces? Because the connection to the repo is handled in respective classes `Git`, `Svn` (say for example in its constructors). So that it looks like

```
class Git implements Repo {
   public Git(String url, String username, String password){
       //connect to git url
   }

   . . . 
}
```

Now is this an fair design with respect to interfaces (in terms of testing) or we need to move the logic of creating connections with repo to say other class like `RepoFactory` and inject them in method params? So that `Repo` interface looks like:

```
interface Repo{
   public JSONObject getBranches(RepoFactory repo)
   public JSONObject getCommits(RepoFactory repo)
   . . . . 
}
```

and we can inject mocking of `RepoFactory` for easy testing.

Which will be an better design? Or something else is better than these two?

Comment: Why not make a test method which accepts `Repo` and simply create an instance of the `Repo` you want to test?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I didnt get that quite

Comment: Why not write a test method which expects `Repo` (`public static void test(Repo repo)`, then it doesn't matter what instance you pass to it, `test(new Git());`??

Comment: @MadProgrammer: So your saying to stick to first pattern only. Right ?

Comment: To me, yes, that doesn't mean it's right ;), but while you certainly should design for testing, don't sacrifice your API's usability for it either ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to test interface? I think you have to test both implementations of your repo: Git and SVN. If you need to test higher logics you can use custom MockRepo implementation that returns mock values, or set up this mock using special frameworks like Moq framework.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what are you trying to test.

Lets say that you have a class A which depends on class B which depends on framework classes.

Now if A is your unit under test then you create a mocked B fake and spy the results according to a given scenario, and test A for soundness.

If you want to test B then it gets tricky and you should ask yourself a question. Does B have any parts that are logical and worth testing? If so they should be either extracted to different class and tested alone, or you can wrap up the framework objects with interface and then it becomes the same as A.

EXAMPLE 1: B is reading a stream of bytes from a framework connection object and passes them to a 3rd party JSON parser and returns the result to A. There is virtually no need to test B, since it only delegates actions to (hopefully) already tested components.

EXAMPLE 2: B is reading a stream of bytes from a framework connection object, and for efficiency reasons parses them to a JSON object by itself then returns the result to A. Well it's pretty obvious that if you introduce a JSON parser, create and test the implementation then the situation becomes exactly like the one in example 1.

But lets say that for some (dumb and wrong) reason you want B to be the component that parses the bytes. In this case it leaves you no choice but to create a wrapping interface over the framework connection object and mock it to return the desired output. The problems with this approach is the unnecessary abstraction of a component that will never have more than one implementation, and the lack of a clear responsibility for B ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

**However there is seem to be a design flaw in your introduction:** I don't know the requirements to your system but this interface will never allow repositories that do not support JSON which seems off to me, and I would recommend to replace it with well defined POJOs. If you are positive that the use in JSON will always be true you should do it anyways! But if you insist, then at least make sure that the return type is your definition of JSON and not some 3rd party object.

In both cases I would use well defined uncoupled POJOs for a single level of abstraction as follows.

```
interface Repo {
   public List<Branch> getBranches();   
   public List<Commit> getCommits();
   . . . . 
}
```

The interfaces Branch and Commit can be easily implemented over JSON elements.